# How to display all checked values first

Tags: javascript, datatables

My Datatable contains a list of values, of which certain are checked. How can I display all the checked values first followed by the unchecked ones

Comment: which database you are using.. and which is datatype of column?

Comment: The database is MySQL, and the datatype is a Boolean

Comment: `ORDER BY column_name DESC` in the end of your SQL statement

Comment: @devdRew
Can you please post it as an answer, so that I can upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your query with an order by statement (isChecked is your boolean)

```
select * from table1 order by isChecked desc
```